# RequestBuilder.sendRequest not getting my JSON from GWT Tutorial

Tags: java, gwt

I'm doing the GWT Tutorial on Retrieving JSON Data (https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/JSON). My code isn't updateing as it should, and on debugging I found that my code is never entering the onResponseReceived Callback method.

This is the code I'm using for this part, copied mostly from the tutorial.

```
// Send request to server and catch any errors.
    RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, url);

    try {
        Request request = builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                displayError("Couldn't retrieve JSON");
            }

            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
                if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
                    updateTable(asArrayOfStockData(response.getText()));
                } else {
                    displayError("Couldn't retrieve JSON (" + response.getStatusText()
                            + ")");
                }
            }
        });
        System.out.println(request.toString());
    } catch (RequestException e) {
        displayError("Couldn't retrieve JSON");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

I added the catch(Exception e) to see if I was getting some sort of other exception breaking my code, but it wasn't. I also did the request.toString() to make sure the request object was actually being created, and when I do I get a string with its MemID or whatever the HEX Number are.

I've been trying to see what's wrong for a while but can't figure it out, so any hints or ideas are very welcome.

Comment: After further investigation, I have found it does access the servlet to get the JSON, but never enters either of the callbacks.

Comment: Anything in firebug or another browser console? If it hits the server, do you see that the server actually finishes and returns?

Comment: I'm not very experienced in this, so I'm not sure about all of this. I'll try and google and post back.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not explaining what exactly problem you are having it is difficult to tell you an exact answer.  So first of all check it with [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/network)(Firebug and Network Monitoring). 
Next suggestion is, you are using GET method so, just enter the URL with some value to parameter named `q` to address bar and hit enter, put break point or see logs on you local server. And also make sure you servlet-mapping in your web.xml is correct.

Comment: The problem was that even though the request was getting through, when debugging the callbacks weren't actually ran. I installed firefox and firebug to test what you said and to my surprise, it works perfectly on firefox.

Comment: It should work on every GWT supported browsers. What browser did you use before, when it didn't work?

Comment: Check it on Chrome press `F12` and go to network tab, check whether everything is fine. is there no stack-trace on the server-side? put break-point at the beginning of the method on the server side. If you are following the above tutorial you mentioned, put the break-point in `JsonStockData` class at the beginning of the doGet() method. If you are using eclipse and don't know how check this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html#usedebug